# I am having an issue with my Firebase login, app keeps stoping?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I created a signup and login form with firebase when i put data in signup form it successfully submitted and store data in firebase when i try to login with same data it shows app keeps stopping. Can anyone help me find why the app keeps on crashing ?

Here is code:

```
public class plogin extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
Button loginbtn,signup;
EditText email,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plogin);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginbtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String mail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }


            if (pass.length()<4){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password too short",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(plogin.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                Intent it=new Intent(plogin.this, com.example.babycare.parentdashboard.class);
                                startActivity(it);

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }


                        }
                    });


        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat :)

Comment: Please share your logs from Android Studio.

Comment: Whats the problem it throws in your stacktrace (logcat)

Comment: Wat is the issue

Comment: Both email and password EditText are null

Comment: signup is working but log is not working when i click on login button it display a pop up message "app keeps stoping"

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanAli , you need to know about logcat, if you dont know what error is throwing is really difficult for us to know what is going on without a trace of the error itself,, see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: As @PeterHaddad said, you need to find your views, because you are accesing them without initializing them in your onCreate() , you need to do a findViewById for email and password EditTexts

Comment: thank you very much all of you my problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please set your email and password fields and attach relevant views to them like below:

```
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```